# excluding title from html using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am getting page html code.

I could remove all html tag and script. Also wanted to remove `<title> whatever here </html>`

Tested all solutions on SO. No help

What's wrong here?

```
function plaintext($html)
    {
        $plaintext = preg_replace('#([<]title)(.*)([<]/title[>])#', ' ', $html);


            //$plaintext = preg_match('#<title>(.*?)</title>#', $html);

        // remove comments and any content found in the the comment area (strip_tags only removes the actual tags).
        $plaintext = preg_replace('#<!--.*?-->#s', '', $plaintext);

        // put a space between list items (strip_tags just removes the tags).
            $plaintext = preg_replace('#</li>#', ' </li>', $plaintext);     

            // remove all script and style tags
        $plaintext = preg_replace('#<(script|style)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</(script|style)>#is', "", $plaintext);

        // remove br tags (missed by strip_tags)
            $plaintext = preg_replace("#<br[^>]*?>#", " ", $plaintext);

            // remove all remaining html
            $plaintext = strip_tags($plaintext);

        return $plaintext;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What is your input, output and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code looks fine. i mean, using your function..

```
function plaintext($html)
{
    $plaintext = preg_replace('#([<]title)(.*)([<]/title[>])#', ' ', $html);

    return $plaintext;
}
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
echo plaintext($page);
```

there's no title tag...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_replace('/<title\b[^>]*>(.*?)</title>/i','',$html);
```